# Replace after decimal SQL

Tags: sqlite, analytics

I am learning SQL and trying make an innings pitched field.

SELECT ROUND((outs / 3), 3) AS innings_pitched, player
FROM pitching;

Currently on output I get a decimal like: 5.33 (5 and 1/3 IP).

How do I convert the decimal into a standard baseball format:

5 and 1/3 IP should read as 5.1
5 and 2/3 IP should read as 5.2
6 whole IP should read as 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accomplished using the [modulo operator](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#operators) (`%`) to get the remainder and [printf](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf) to format the output.

Example:

```
SELECT printf("%i.%i",outs/3,outs % 3) as innings_pitched,  player FROM pitching;
```